# URL for image not working properly in CSS

Tags: css, background, background-image, browser-sync

```
#logo-img {
    background: url('/images/logo.png') no-repeat;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 10px 15px 10px 0;
}
```

The image doesn't show up, but when I use browser-sync through termial it works.

I don't understand what browser-sync does to make it work.

Comment: Have you tried to force the refreshing of the page in your browser?

Comment: yes,several times

Comment: are you sure that the image is at that path from the css file? What does your sturcture look like for the css and images?

Comment: Check if the `.png` extension is case-sensitive.  This is a common oversight, and it matters.

Comment: @Dejan.S  yes the url was wrong, i should have used url('../images/logo.png'). but how on earth was it working with browser-sync??

Comment: hi, that's because an url starting with a / needs a root. testing your site in a (local) server will use / as the root of your site. While loading the page from disk , / will be c:/....

Comment: @Rmaxx , now i got it  thanks for clarification.